# How to display a filtered admin list based off of a count of foreign keys in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I am trying to define a proxy model for my admin view and have it only show objects that have a certain amount of foreign key values.

This is what I'm trying, but I'm not able to filter on yVotes:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class PostVote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    vote = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class VotedPost(models.Post):
    def _yVotes(self):
        return models.PostVote.objects.filter(post=self, vote='Y').count()
    yVotes = property(_yVotes)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True 

class VotedPostAdmin(PostAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'yVotes')
    def queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(yVotes__gt=0)
```

So my end result would be when you browse to /admin page for VotedPost, it would only show posts that have more than 0 'Y' votes. Commenting out the queryset in VotedPostAdmin, the proper value for yVotes will display in the list_display.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I've ended up with so far to get me the results I need. If anyone has a more elegant solution I will wait to accept:

```
class VotedPostAdmin(PostAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'yVotes')
    def queryset(self, request):        
    return VotedPost.objects.all().annotate(count = Count('postvote')).order_by('-count').filter(count__gt=0).filter(postvote__vote='Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you overwrite get_queryset or use the admin filters to create such display. What you're trying todo seems overly complex tbh

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ThisAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        # do stuff and return whatever
```

Comment: I'm okay with simplifying things, just not sure how to get the results I want. I'm only a week into django so still learning. We want to have two different admin links, one for all posts and one for just the posts with votes. I'm looking into the admin filter route.